# How to pass Authorization TOKEN into Python requests header

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, authorization, token

I am trying to make a http request using Python3.8.5 + requests 2.25.0. The request contains Authorization Token in the header.

When use Postman to make the request, I can get response without issue. But, when I use following python code to make the request, it returns 401. Not sure what is worng in the code.

```
401  {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

Following are the python code having issues.

```
import requests

url = <MY_URL>

payload={}
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'TOKEN <MY_TOKEN>'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

Comment: Code looks ok. Are you setting <MY_TOKEN> to correct value??

Comment: same token works fine use Postman. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem resloved by adding a / at the end of the request url. :-)